# Writing a Gem -- How to manage configuration settings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm new to the gem-writing world, and I'm trying to make sure that my gem is as flexible as it can be out of the box. I've got a couple configuration options that will need to be set for things like testing, but I'd like for those options to be able to be overridden at the Ruby on Rails level.

I know that certain gems like Devise do this already, but I'm not sure exactly how it should be accomplished (primarily from the "put these files here, put those files there" kind of perspective). Can anyone give me any tips or suggestions?

Edit: What I'm really looking to know is how these gems manage having configuration settings defined locally to the gem and having them defined in Rails, and defining for the Rails application which takes precedence.

Comment: A large number of gems (Carrierwave, fog, devise, omniauth to name a few) put their configuration files in `config/intializers`

Comment: I understand that half, sorry, my question isn't very good. I'm wondering how they manage having config values defined in the gem and then allowing those configurations to be overridden in the Rails settings themselves. I'll edit the question.

Comment: you mean something like this?  --->  def x(params) defaults = {:bah => 1, :beh =>2, :bih => 3}; mod_params = defaults.merge(params); puts "modified_params:#{mod_params}" end

Comment: Is it that simple? Just merging the param hashes?

Comment: you could also use a gem that helps you with those issues like confiture does: https://github.com/phoet/confiture/

Comment: @phoet, I think we'll do that, thanks for the help. If you want to add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are gems that help you create rails initializer style configuration.

an example is https://github.com/phoet/confiture/